# MSSQL Create time schedule for minutes

Tags: sql-server

I give two parameter begindate and enddate

example

```
@begindate = '2012-01-01'
@endate = '2013-01-01'
```

result as

```
begindate             enddate
2012-01-01 00:00:00   2012-01-01 00:10:00
2012-01-01 00:10:00   2012-01-01 00:20:00
2012-01-01 00:20:00   2012-01-01 00:30:00
```

like this how

i write this code

```
create table Test
(
a datetime,
b datetime 
)

DECLARE @BeginDate date = '2012-01-01'

DECLARE @EndDate date = '2012-12-31'

DECLARE @beginValue int = 1

DECLARE @count int =  DATEDIFF ( day , '2012-01-01' , '2012-12-31' )
DECLARE @dayHours INT = 0 
DECLARE @dayHoursLimit INT = 23
DECLARE @Minute INT = 0
DECLARE @MinuteLimit INT= 50
DECLARE @CountOfMinute INT =10

while @beginValue <= @count 
begin

    SET @BeginDate=  DATEADD(DAY,1, @BeginDate);

    WHILE @dayHours <= @dayHoursLimit
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Minute <= @MinuteLimit
        BEGIN
            insert into TEST

            SELECT CAST(CAST(@BeginDate AS VARCHAR(10)) +' '+CAST(@dayHours AS varchar(2)) +':'+CAST (@Minute AS varchar(2)) AS datetime) as a , 
            CAST(CAST(@BeginDate AS VARCHAR(10)) +' '+CAST(@dayHours AS varchar(2)) +':'+CAST (@Minute +@CountOfMinute AS varchar(2)) AS datetime) as b
            0 AS B
            SET @Minute = @Minute + @CountOfMinute      
         END
    SET @Minute = 0
    SET @dayHours = @dayHours +1
END
    SET @dayHours = 0
    SET @beginValue = @beginValue +1
END
```

Comment: can you further explain your question? i really dont know what you're asking...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you want to generate one row for every 10 minute interval between `@BeginDate` and `@EndDate`. If so, use recursive CTE:

```
DECLARE @BeginDate  datetime = '2012-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate    datetime = '2013-01-01'

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT @BeginDate AS BeginDate,
            DATEADD(minute, 10, @BeginDate) AS EndDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(minute, 10, BeginDate),
            DATEADD(minute, 20, BeginDate)
    FROM cte
    WHERE BeginDate < DATEADD(minute,-10,@EndDate)
)

SELECT * FROM cte
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```